# Why does the sudo command not work in chroot?

Tags: sudo, chroot

I just installed a 32-bit `chroot` to run on my 64-bit system. In the `chroot` environment, the `sudo` command doesn't work, it says

> sudo: command not found

Also, when I try the `su root` command, my password doesn't work (`su: authentication failure`). What password do they want?

I'm quite new to Ubuntu, so actually I don't really know what I'm doing. I am just trying to follow instructions.

---

I solved this particular problem simply by starting the `chroot` by the command:

```
katarina@ubuntu:~$ schroot -c oneiric_i386 -u root
```

instead of the one I used the first time:

```
katarina@ubuntu:~$ schroot -a
```

I still have some other problems, but I guess that's not for this question.

Comment: Well you may have just described the error: You are running 32-bit software on a 64-bit system!

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion the question is more about not understanding what chroot does.

It moves the / to wherever you tell it, so there's no more /bin, /sbin, or /usr.

This means you're not going to have sudo anymore since it lives in one of those directories.

Answer (score 6):

You must install sudo in the chroot'ed environment:

```
apt-get install sudo
```

Comment: Unreal, can't believe it doesn't come shipped by default

Answer (score 2):

When you start a chroot environment, you are generally already root, so you don't need to use `sudo` or `su root`.

If you need to use a non-root user account, you need to create it first, and login as that user with (in the chroot)

```
login myuser
```

or

```
su - myuser
```

Next, if you want to let that user to use `sudo`, you need to add it to the `admin` group into the chroot.

Comment: I see. No I want to use the root-account. But if I skip the sudo it sais permission denied:        (oneiric_i386)katarina@ubuntu:~$ apt-get install vim
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: @katarina: but this command is run inside the `chroot`? Have you issued the `chroot /path` command?

Comment: yes cause I couldn't find an editor in the `chroot` environment. I don't know wht you mean by the `chroot /path` command, what does it do? Sorry this is new to me.

Comment: @katarina: I suggest to review your `chroot` information with the following page [Basic `chroot`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot).

Answer (score 1):

There's more to it than you think to get a working chroot jail. In your example, it's because the `sudo` command is in `/bin` and not available in your new root. But just installing the base packages to the new root won't do the trick, you also need to mount a /`proc`, `/sys` and `/dev` for the jail, probably create a couple of symbolic nodes, definitely a `tty` and for most practical purposes, it probably won't work without a `random` too. You do that with `mknod`.

Now all that sounds complicated, and to be honest, it is a bit involved. Debian based distros have a simpler way of dealing with it, namely, `debootstrap`, for which you can find a basic [how-to tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) in the Ubuntu help site.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention sudoers?

Comment: @SamB Should be automagically created by installing the sudo package to the new root.