# How to make a lib file (libtxc-dxtn0) used by only the apps that need it?

Tags: libraries

I need libtxc-dxtn for some native Linux games to start (Amnesia). Without it, the game crashes. If I install it, the colors some other games  drastically change. So, I install and un-install the package, depending on what I have to start.

Is there a way to provide the lib to the apps that only need it? I hope my question is clear enough

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: This is probably going to be a pain, but have you tried running the games that don't use `libtxc-dxtn` in a `chroot` envorinment?(See http://askubuntu.com/questions/56687/how-to-chroot-ubuntu1 and http://askubuntu.com/a/120704/54298)

Comment: Look into extracting the shared libraries in the package in an alternate location and then using `LD_PRELOAD` and/or modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Link how to do this? Tried by got core dumped error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LD_PRELOAD='/home/deckoff/Desktop/libtxc/libtxc_dxtn.so' /opt/amnesia/Launcher.bin
```

This did the trick. Lib was marked as executable, owner is root, not user.( dont know if this is needed or not). I have made a syntax error in my first tries- I have left some space between "=" and "'", there should not be any.